# How to calculate two complex number by add.

Tags: complex-numbers

This equation 
$$\frac{1}{5}(1+2e^{-j(2π/5)} + 3e^{-j(4π/5)}) = 0.75e^{-j1.79}$$

How do you get the result? $j$ is a imaginary part.

Comment: Are we supposed to calculate j?

Comment: Is $j = \sqrt{-1}$ the imaginary unit?

Comment: yes, $j = \sqrt{-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\frac{1}{5}(1+2(\cos\frac{2\pi}{5}-j\sin\frac{2\pi}{5})+3(\cos \frac{4\pi}{5}-j\sin \frac{4\pi}{5}))$$ $$=\frac{1}{5}(1+2\cos \frac{2\pi}{5}-3\cos \frac{\pi}{5} -j(2\sin \frac{2\pi}{5}+3\sin \frac{\pi}{5}))$$ $$=\frac{1}{5}(1+2(2\cos^2\frac{\pi}{5}-1)-3\cos \frac{\pi}{5}-j(4\sin \frac{\pi}{5}\cos \frac{\pi}{5}+3\sin \frac{\pi}{5}))$$ $$=\frac{1}{5}(1+2(2(\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{8})-1)-3(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4})-j(4(\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}{4})(\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{4})+3\frac{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{5}}}{4})$$

Can you take it from here??

Answer (score 0):

You use [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$$e^{jx}=\cos (x)+j \sin (x)$$
and crank through.  The equation as given is wrong because the exponent on the right should not be exactly $1.79$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg((1%2B2e%5E(-2i%20pi%2F5)%2B3e%5E(-4i%20pi%2F5))%2F5)) gives it as about $-1.7880267$

Comment: Could you write the calculation step?  I am not sure how to use the formula to get the result.